# How can I make a INNER JOIN in the Laravel relationships?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is `purchase_order` model:

```
class purchase_order extends Model
{
    protected $table = "purchase_order";

    public function commodities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(commodities::class, 'purchase_order_id', 'id')->where('invoiced', 1);
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
purchase_order::with("invoiced_commodities")->get();
```

It returns all `purchase_order` with along their `invoiced-commodities`. All fine.

---

As far as I know, it behaves like `LEFT JOIN`, because it returns `purchase_order` that doesn't have any `invoiced-commodities`. Now I need to make it like `INNER JOIN`. I mean I want to get only `purchase_orders` that have at least one `invoiced-commodities`. Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
$purchase_orders = purchase_order::has("invoiced_commodities")->get();
```

Aslo see docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 3):

> I want to get only purchase_orders that have at least one invoiced-commodities

```
// Retrieve all purchase orders that has at least one invoiced commodities
purchase_order::has("invoiced_commodities")->get();
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)